# Regex101 generated code gives error. (python)

Tags: python, regex

I used [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/#python) to test a simple regex (\D+\n*), but the code generated gives a syntax error.

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur"\D+\n*", re.UNICODE)
test_str = u"2080 usec, 240 usec\n1780 usec, 260 usec\n700 usec, 240 usec\n700 usec, 240 usec\n2480 usec, 240 usec\n700 usec, 240 usec\n700 usec, 240 usec\n"
subst = u""

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

What's wrong? Using python 3.4.3.

Comment: Can you provide the syntax error?

Comment: It highlights the second " in "\D+\n*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ur` prefix is [not supported in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals). Use `r` instead.

Python 2.7:

```
>>> ur"\D+\n*"
u'\\D+\\n*'
```

Python 3:

```
>>> ur"foo"
  File "<ipython-input-12-e07f08d3b66c>", line 1
    ur"foo"
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is one of the least helpful Python errors I've seen, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Use only `r` string prefix instead of `ur`.

Comment: Works great, why is this an issue?

Comment: The combined prefix is not supported in the recent versions of Python3.

Comment: doesn't really explain why the error was shown at the end of the literal though

Answer (score 0):

If you import `re`, and use `re.compile(r'\D+\n*')`, it seems to work.

What exactly was wrong though I do not know.

Comment: I do import, forgot to copy. THX